# Dart object as a value

Tags: dart, object

I remember that Dart objects have a method which does an object return a value by default without pointing to an property. Example:

```
class A {
  final String name;
  A(this.name);
  ...
}

main() {
  var obj = A('chesu');
  print(obj + ' locuaz');
}
```

Output: `chesu locuaz`

But I don't remember that method or decorator and it is not `toString()`.

Comment: You are misremembering.  There is no automatic way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found what I was looking for, it's called [callable classes](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/concept-of-callable-classes-in-dart/).

Answer (score 0):

Use interpolation to compose strings and values. It will automatically call toString method of value.

```dart
class A {
  A(this.name);
  final String name;
  
  @override
  toString() => name;
}

main() {
  var obj = A('chesu');
  print('$obj locuaz');
}
```